# Is using the XML datatype as a DataTable acceptable?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

For some reason I feel like I'm going about this the painful way. 
I have an INSERT xml list. I'm using XML because I need to pass in more than one dynamic value. Since we're saving the event, I already have that ID. What I won't know is the Group or Room ID, so I'm using XML to essentially pass in a datatable.

Here is an example INSERT portion:

```
IF @eventGroupTagRoomListInsert IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO EventGroupTagRoomLink(EventID, RoomID, GroupTagID, IsDeleted, LastModifiedBy, SessionID)
            SELECT
                @eventID AS EventID,
                ParamValues.Id.query('RoomId').value('.', 'int') AS RoomID,
                ParamValues.Id.query('GroupTagID').value('.', 'int') AS GroupTagID,
                0 AS IsDeleted,
                @lastModifiedBy  AS LastModifiedBy,
                @sessionId AS SessionID
            FROM @eventGroupTagRoomListInsert.nodes('/Entities/entity') AS ParamValues(ID)
        IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ERR_HANDLER
    END
```

Is there cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say yes, is acceptable.

In theory in SQL 2008 you have [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) which may be simpler, as syntax at least:

```
INSERT INTO EventGroupTagRoomLink
  (EventID, RoomID, GroupTagID, IsDeleted, LastModifiedBy, SessionID) 
SELECT EventID, RoomID, GroupTagID, IsDeleted, LastModifiedBy, SessionID 
FROM @eventGroupTagRoomTVP
```

But between backward compatibility issues (does not work on 2005) and the rather unfriendly manner to present the [TVP to ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) (must be a datatable or DbDataReader, will not accept for example a linq query expression) I'm not sure I'd move to TVP over XML.

Answer (score 2):

No problems with this approach.

I use it in several places because it's an effective wayx (especially in SQL Server 2005+) to deal with arrays and lists

[Erland and his famous "Arrays and Lists" article](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

If you read it and the tests too, XML is *usually* the fastest "standalone" (no CLR needed) method